# When to use DiagnosticActorLogging instead of ActorLogging traits in Akka?

Tags: logging, akka, mdc

What is the difference between `ActorLogging` and `DiagnosticActorLogging` traits in `Akka` and when should you favor one over the other?  A quick look at the [docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.6/scala/logging.html) doesn't provide much guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MDC allows you to add additional context to messages you log. For example, with logging pattern `%5p %X{user-id} %m%n`, inserting `user-id` in mdc map will substitute the value in the template field `%X{user-id}`

`DiagnosticActorLogging` provides you an easy access to `mdc` and takes care of setting and clearing mdc for each message processed by the actor. Take a look at `aroundReceive` method in `DiagnosticActorLogging` trait to understand it better

```
override protected[akka] def aroundReceive(receive: Actor.Receive, msg: Any): Unit = try {
    log.mdc(mdc(msg))
    super.aroundReceive(receive, msg)
  } finally {
    log.clearMDC()
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to figure it out is to go check the DiagnosticActorLogging sources:

```
/**
 * Scala API: Mix in DiagnosticActorLogging into your Actor to easily obtain a reference to a logger with MDC support,
 * which is available under the name "log".
 * In the example bellow "the one who knocks" will be available under the key "iam" for using it in the logback pattern.
 *
 * {{{
 * class MyActor extends Actor with DiagnosticActorLogging {
 *
 *   override def mdc(currentMessage: Any): MDC = {
 *     Map("iam", "the one who knocks")
 *   }
 *
 *   def receive = {
 *     case "pigdog" => log.info("We've got yet another pigdog on our hands")
 *   }
 * }
 * }}}
 */
trait DiagnosticActorLogging extends Actor {
  import akka.event.Logging._
  val log = akka.event.Logging(this)
  def mdc(currentMessage: Any): MDC = emptyMDC

  override protected[akka] def aroundReceive(receive: Actor.Receive, msg: Any): Unit = try {
    log.mdc(mdc(msg))
    super.aroundReceive(receive, msg)
  } finally {
    log.clearMDC()
  }
}
```

Basically it allows to implicitly associate some shared pieces of logging data to every logging call in the actor without all the clutter of adding them explicitly. Depending on your application, it may be useful for things like host name, request id, client id, jar version, build date, endpoint etc.